# Create a custom resolution on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I would like to create a custom resolution on Windows 10, but I don't find the way to do it; on Windows 7 was simple, because I click on the right button on the desktop and there was "NVIDIA control panel" or something, and from here I could create a new. I've read that Windows 10 doesn't easily allow you to do this, is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include how you created custom resolutions in Windows 7.

Comment: Have you installed the nVidia utilities for Windows 10?  Are you even still using an nVidia card?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Windows 10, go to Settings (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) > System > Display > Scale and layout > Resolution. There is some list of resolution.

[image: Resolution]

To find more resolution setting, Scroll down, click on **Display adapter Properties**. You can see this window (this may vary if your display driver is different).

[image: Graphics Properties]

From there select **List All Modes**. There you can find many other Resolution options.

[image: All Modes]

There is also a 3rd party software to make custom Resolution setting:: [MonitorTests:Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)

Comment: My selection in Windows does not allow me to access all the modes available in the display adapter list. I wish to get to 640x480 (for retro gaming). Any ideas? EDIT: Oops. I can set it from the display adapters page! Thank you!

Comment: After selecting a "wrong" resolution through the `list all modes` option and then clicking `Revert` the bug of resolution mismatch was fixed and now the correct resolution is available and displayed on the monitor.

Answer (score 8):

If your resolution is not listed in the resolution options, have a look at the software of your graphics card.

In my case I could add a custom resolution in my **Intel control panel**: Go to "Display" -> "Custom Resolution" and enter your values there.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Scaled Resolution Editor](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Scaled-Resolution-Editor-SRE). It operates on scaled resolutions, so a lot safer than CRU because it does not tinker with the native resolution of the display.