# Want to set 3840x2160 resolution (16:9) on a 16:10 laptop

Tags: resolution, 4k-resolution

I have a laptop with a 4K display (Asus Vivobook 16", M5602QA). The display ratio is 16:10.
I would like to occasionally set it to 16:9 so that my zoom calls screen share shows full screen on other 16:9 screens. The problem is that the 16:9 resolution (3840x2160) is missing in the list in the settings.

I'm using Windows 11. Does anyone know if it's possible to somehow add that resolution to the list?

[image]

Comment: In win10 click in that same window clock advanced display settings > display adapter properties > click button 'list all modes, you'll have more options there in that list. BTW, best to edit question and include your OS.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Got the same list of modes as shown in the picture above. 3840x2160 is missing. What's interesting is that the laptop has no issues connecting to a 4k monitor 16:9 ratio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a custom resolution on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1209385/create-a-custom-resolution-on-windows-10)

Comment: The [Scaled resolution editor](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Scaled-Resolution-Editor-SRE) got the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Scaled Resolution Editor](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Scaled-Resolution-Editor-SRE) got the job done. The 3840x2160 resolution was already in the list of available modes, I just had to enable with a couple of mouse clicks and reboot.

Comment: Nice. Please be so kind to accept your own answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Your display adapter may not offer the resolution of 3840x2160.

Try the free
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU):

> Custom Resolution Utility (CRU) is an EDID editor that focuses on custom resolutions. CRU shows you how the monitor defines resolutions and other capabilities and gives you the power to change it. Add custom resolutions, remove unwanted resolutions, edit FreeSync ranges, and more. CRU creates software EDID overrides in the registry and does not modify the hardware.

Be aware that forcing a non-supported resolution may have
unforeseen effects.